# how enabled key for show gmap v2 in android

Tags: android, google-maps, ggmap

i just wanna show gmap in my project, but when my app running it's showing blank map, like this
[image]

and this is my logcat

[image]

this is for my developer console

[image]

list enable API
[image]

and this is my manifest, [load more](http://pasted.co/53f959d5)

what's wrong for my code or my setting console dev ??

Answer (score 0):

Its quite sure from the logcat that the issue is with the API_KEY. Either the key that you have put in the manifest file is from some other project or you have not enabled the Google Maps Android API v2.

Here is what I found out from the images you provided:

- The key in the Manifest file and the Key that is generated in your console ***does not match***.
- Make sure that you have enabled the ***Google Maps Android API V2***.